# How to make Google search not redirect

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

When I click an entry in the Google search results, it first queries Google server and then redirect to the page. For example, search `foobar` gives:

```
<a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=foobar&amp;source=web&amp;cd=1&amp;ved=0CC4QFjAA&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar2000.org%2F&amp;ei=d9jBTsX8DqGyiQfhrJWhBQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNGQknEqVa-v5EXzIMs9jCwNJ8VU2w" target="_blank" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNGQknEqVa-v5EXzIMs9jCwNJ8VU2w','','0CC4QFjAA')"><em>foobar2000</em></a>
```

The long href redirects to Google first, and then redirects to www.foobar2000.com.

Well, I don't mind Google use my click stats to modify its page ranks. I do also not care about privacy, but as you know with Internet censorship in China, the links redirected by Google are often broken.

In real life, I usually copy&paste the web addresses, rather then click on them directly.

Is there any way (Firefox/Chrome plugin maybe?) to disable the redirection in the Google search results?

I'm also thinking that Google should make the sending back in another Ajax request, so even users out of China don't have to wait for the respond of the redirection.

Comment: The simplest workaround may be to use an extension which automatically converts plain text URLs to clickable ones. Try that first.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22313/15928

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much about the china issue.

I think this is one, add PDA to  google http://www.google.com/pda , its sleek fast and everything google once was before they dropped the values of simplicity. It even has usefull options for setting time ranges, or viewing mostly forums, and takes the normal added parameters.  everything that google was when it was made the most popular search engine. the Adds still are adds, or do we call that shopping :-)

Same thing http://www.google.com/xhtml Google mobile

Original Google http://www.google.com/custom , to bad it has not worked for me in a long time.

Switch, who really has liked the progress that google has put apon us?  http://duckduckgo.com/   what google once was complete with goofey name like google once was :-)   you can click on the displayed links direct or the header. Hint, look in the setting, looks like it was made by real developers?

Comment: Bad luck, both /pda and /xhtml are redirecting. /custom seems not accessible. Well, `duckduckgo.com` is clickable, but it is duckduckgo...

Comment: It only seemed to redirect on the sales type links? or those top links, which are "different" (i dont know if they are paid for) I tested it with many types of searches?

Comment: I just checked DuckDuckGo, and its searc results also are redirect links.

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna check out this nice add-on:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-no-tracking-url/