# Turning off Google search results indirection

Tags: google-search, privacy

In Google search results, in Firefox or Chrome, I get URLs that go through Google and not directly to the target site. For example, at

http://www.google.com/search?q=foo

the first result is

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=foo&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFoobar&ei=gBj9TtDpAcXT8QPI_4GdAQ&usg=AFQjCNH1J2pXAETcCKA7T6svhOKIRNyojg

I don't really care that Google is tracking what I click, and I don't really care about the extra indirection when I click on a result (though both are concerns). But I find it annoying that I can't copy-paste a result by simply right-clicking on a link and choosing “copy link address” (I want to get the real result, not Google's redirection to it).

I want to have the direct URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar, at least for copy-paste purposes, in Firefox and Chrome.

Google's behavior changed several times:

- When I asked this question, in a browser without Javascript, you got direct URLs in results: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar. The indirection was added via Javascript.
- Some time later, Google changed to provide indirect results in all browsers.
- Since 2012-09-04, it seems that:

  - In a browser without JS, the HTML still contains indirect results.
  - In a browser with JS support (at least in recent Firefox and Chrome), the HTML contains a direct result in the `href` attribute, but there is an `onmousedown` attribute that invokes the [`rwt` function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22303) which does rewrite the link. You see the direct link when you hover, but you get an indirect link like the one above when you click or copy-paste.

Comment: Didn't realise this doesn't happen in Opera

Comment: This doesn't happen in my Firefox too

Comment: Don't turn it off.

Google uses those clicks to see that you didn't like the results and adjust the page rating.

Comment: @Barfieldmv it's like you don't care about the other, valid reasons to turn it off.

Comment: I didn't see any reason posted why google uses this redirection. (my tone might be a bit off though since I'm a non native english speaker) I was trying to add an argument to keep it turned on.

Comment: What they need to do is detect which mouse button triggered the  `mousedown` event and only change the link to the redirect if `event.button !== 2` (2 is right click).

Comment: Reloading the page removes the extra directions..

Comment: They do that to protect your privacy. Your search url may have private information about you. Facebook does the same thing. So webmasters can not track who clicked the url/

Comment: My search experience has dramatically improved the moment I turned javascript off on google.com. No indirections, no useless previews, no ugly buttons popping all over the place on hover. Instead, a fast, clean, minimalist interface we were all used to five years back. Google really does terrible UX.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch: You can right-click and open the URL, too, so that solution isn't sufficient (assuming, of course, that there is good reason for the redirect to be needed, which according to Oguz Bilgic there is)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy link found by Google search](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/copy-link-found-by-google-search)

Comment: When testing an anti-tracking script/extension, make sure not to fall for Google’s deceptive tracker-hiding. When you do a search, hovering the cursor over a link shows the correct URL, but clicking causes it to revert to the tracking server. When you install a script, you can make sure it is actually working by **right-clicking** a link *before* looking at the status bubble. Also, note that Web Search **isn’t the only Google site that does this**; GMail, Image Search, YouTube, etc. do it as well, but most anti-tracking scripts only support Web Search. Make sure to use one that is pan-Google.

Comment: They do it for tracking purposes i.e using what keyword you came across the site etc. etc. And also for displaying relavant AdSense ads. It's not important at all, if you don't care about Google's damn stat report ;)

Comment: I don't like Google rewriting the links because it's sleazy, and it slows down my browsing experience. Bah to data-saferedirecturl

Comment: I can't post my answer as im new. I think the simplest solution is to go to the Google cached version of the page, then at the top you can see the page's raw address. -I've made a screenshot but can't post it in a comment.

Comment: @plm That doesn't work if I don't want Google to know which link I clicked! Or if I want to cut down the hassle, which is my motivation most of the time (and why I still use the “Don't track me Google”) extension to this day.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks. Personnally i just want to copy the raw link -like when there is an autodownloading pdf which does not open the target page- so i didn't think of the tracking. My solution is not for every need but it is still the simplest. :)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> *Author's note (July 2016):* The answer below was written in 2011, and still works in Google Search. I have since published new extensions that use a different method to remove the search result indirection and they work on even more Google sites as well as on mobile.

**TL;DR:** [Don't track me Google](https://github.com/Rob--W/dont-track-me-google) is an extension I made that allows you to copy normal URLs, while hiding the referrer to the sites you're visiting.

### Installation

- ["Don't track me Google"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg) at the Chrome Web Store (updated in 2016).

- ["Don't track me Google"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dont-track-me-google1/) for Firefox (desktop & Android) (since 2016).

- ["Don't track me Google"](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424090201/https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121923) from the Internet Archive of Userscripts.org.  (works in Google search only and is no longer updated).

### Explanation

I have written a method that replaces the link-modifying `rwt` function with a bogus function that can't be touched by Google.

By preventing Google from overwriting the `rwt` function, the link can no longer be modified. This method depends on the `Object.defineProperty` method ([Firefox 4+ and Chrome 5+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility)). The fallback requires [Firefox 2+ and Chrome 1+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get#Browser_compatibility).

### Firefox 2+

If you only want to remove the link-modifying behaviour, and don't mind showing your search queries through the referrer, this GreaseMonkey script can be used:
*(very non-strict `@include` rules using wildcards and the [Magic TLD](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Magic_TLD))*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Don't track me Google
// @namespace      Rob W
// @include        http://*.google.tld/*
// @include        https://*.google.tld/*
// @version        1.2
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

"use strict";
if (Object.defineProperty) {
   Object.defineProperty(unsafeWindow,"rwt", {value: function(){return !0;}, writable: false });
} else {
   unsafeWindow.__defineGetter__('rwt',function(){return function(){return !0}});
}
```

Google Chrome does not support [Magic TLDs](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Magic_TLD), so the closest you can get is `*://*.google.com/*` (repeat the rule, replace `.com` with other [supported Google TLDs](https://www.google.com/supported_domains)).

In Chrome, scripts have to be injected in the form of a `<script>` tag, because Content scripts [are executed in an "isolated world"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

### Chrome & Firefox 2+ - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424090201/http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/121923.user.js) to source code

On January 21st, 2012, I published an extended version, which includes a referrer-hiding method, so that others cannot see your search query. This greatly improves your privacy.

- The mechanism is explained at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8957778/938089?what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-hide-spoof-the-referrer-in-javascript/8957778#8957778)** on Stack Overflow.
- Additional details are available at the [source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424090201/http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/121923.user.js) and **[Don't track me Google description](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424090201/https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121923)**, a user script which fixes the URIs ***and*** hides the referrer.

**2016 Update:** Referrer hiding is no longer needed in modern browsers because of the [referrer policy](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/21/meta-referrer/), which only shows the domain in the Referer header)

Comment: This didn't work for me, is it still working for others? I was able to get the following script working: `document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function () { /* loop over all links and remove the onmousedown attribute */ }, false);`

Comment: @tehDorf It still works for me. I've edited my answer to update the links, and added `@grant none` to make sure that the user script runs in the page's context.

Comment: As of 2016, Gmail rewrites links too. Please could you add support to your extension?

Comment: @ColonelPanic Sorry for the delay, I have published a new version (also for Firefox) and updated the answer. It is also [on Github](https://github.com/Rob--W/dont-track-me-google).

Answer (score 49):

See if the userscript found [here](http://sumtips.com/2011/12/get-clean-unmodified-url.html) for Google search works for you. I have been using it for a while now, and it's been working more often than not for me.
[image]

**Edit:** Here is an addon for Firefox: [Google search link fix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/)

Comment: The twitter one is working beautifully for me. Neither Facebook nor Google seem to work though... Using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: This will always disable the rewriting, which means that sensitive information will not be removed from the referrer (see e.g. http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/protecting-privacy-with-referrers/392382738919).  Is there a way to copy the original URL to the clipboard when needed, but still rewrite it when the link is followed normally?

Comment: This no longer works in Chrome with the new policy of blocking non-store extensions/scripts.

Answer (score 24):

Appears the *rwt* function is invoked upon *onmousedown*, and thereby rewriting the href. If we could override this behaviour, then we should be set.

In firefox I inserted the following JavaScript into a bookmarklet which can then be executed anytime I wish to prevent the (slighly annoying) link-rewriting on a given Google SERP:

```
javascript:function rwt(a,f,g,l,m,h,c,n,i){return a};
```

Edit: Great to see that the userscript @Rob has created and included in his reply takes advantage of this snippet, highly recommended!

Comment: As an aside, you can knock out all of the parameters for `rwt` except `a` in this case, because JavaScript doesn't care if the arguments to a function match the parameters or not.

Comment: good point. and FWIW, I suspect `javascript:function rwt(){0};` might produce a similar result, even without the `0` -- perhaps worthy of asking over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) since this is both untested and slightly offtopic.

Answer (score 13):

I use the Firefox [Redirect Remover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirect-remover/) add-on.

After this is installed, right click on a redirected URL in the browser gives an option to copy cleaned URL.

Answer (score 13):

### Solutions without any browser extension or JavaScript

If you want to keep Google's redirection and only selectively copy & paste some URLs here are other possibilities which do not require any change in the browser. **Unfortunately while the solutions work in Firefox they do not seem to work in Chrome and Internet Explorer any more.**

**Solution with keyboard (tested in Linux and Windows):**
Navigate to the desired search result link:

- in Firefox: use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between links;
- in Chrome: press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus into the page, then <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate between search results. (“Copy Link Address” not available if you reach the search result with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.)

Then press the context menu key or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select “Copy Link Location” / “Copy Link Address” (hot key: <kbd>A</kbd> in English Firefox, <kbd>E</kbd> in English Chrome).

**Making the keyboard navigation faster using a mouse:**
For faster navigation in Firefox using the mouse, you can click a white-space or an non-link text before the link and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You can also switch to the caret navigation using <kbd>F7</kbd> and use cursor keys or <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

**Solution with mouse only:**
In some browsers and environments (e.g. Firefox on Windows) it is possible to press the right mouse button outside of the link, move the mouse cursor while keeping the button still pressed and then release the button on the link to invoke the context menu.

**Explanation:**
The described ways avoid clicking the mouse on the link and invoking the `onmousedown` event which causes the conversion of the original URL. Note that if you already clicked the link, you must reload the search results page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to get the original URL back.

Comment: There is no F10 on a Mac keyboard. Any Mac instructions?

Comment: @SamtheBrand: Please do not write that something works only in Windows when it does not work in Mac. Are they the only operating systems? I am happily using this solution on Linux. --- As the answer explains the aim of the solution is to open the context menu on the link using a keyboard. **I have no experience with Macs** but as I understand it they are very limited when it comes to control without a mouse. Maybe you as a Mac user can find a solution easier. It seems that Mac+Space is possible in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81727

Comment: @SamtheBrand: Also here: http://blogs.uoregon.edu/developments/2010/10/15/mac-osx-and-firefox-contextual-menu-aka-right-click-menu-from-the-keyboard/ I guess that another solution will not work as it probably emulates a mouse button press: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu#Implementation

Comment: Apologies, you're correct that it's not "only Windows." Any chance you can edit your (great) answer to include the info you've expressed in comments here? This question and your answer and others here will soon be syndicated at Lifehacker. It would be great if we can get your edits to the editors in time!

Comment: @SamtheBrand: I will edit the answer but could you please confirm if **Mac**+**Space** works in Firefox on Mac and possibly try other possibilities / in other browsers (the one I linked from Wikipedia)? By the way which Mac keyboard is missing F10? I have found pictures of many layouts and all had F10 but anyway I am almost sure that **Shift**+**F10** does not show context menu on Mac.

Answer (score 11):

For short URLs, you can just copy the green text under the title as that's the same URL just without protocol lead.

For long URLs (those that have ellipsis in the green text), you either need a script or use a semi-complex workaround.

A script is necessary because Google modifies links with its own script on mouse click. If you hover over a results link, you'll notice in the status bar that it displays properly but it changes upon your interaction with it.

The workaround consists of opening Developer Tools in Chrome or FireBug in Firefox, selecting the link with element inspector, and copying the content of href attribute. This requires 2 windows to be open, so it's not the most convenient workflow on smaller screens.

You could've done it with `View source` but Google Instant sometimes results in strange source. Also, in order to find the link in the source you must remember its title as there's no visual selector as in Developer Tools & FireBug.

Comment: That's an annoyingly twisty workaround, more complicated than doing the search in w3m. Is there a way to disable the redirection once and for all through a user script?

Comment: I just tried the only 2 scripts on www.userscripts.org that claim to do just that (the most recent one is dated Feb 2011). Neither of them works in Chrome or Firefox/Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 11):

Extensions for Chrome and Firefox:

- ***Chrome*** extension:

  - [**Undirect**

    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undirect/dohbiijnjeiejifbgfdhfknogknkglio](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undirect/dohbiijnjeiejifbgfdhfknogknkglio)
    → https://github.com/xwipeoutx/undirect

  BEFORE:
  [image: Before enabling Undirect]

  AFTER:
  [image: After enabling Undirect]
- ***Firefox*** extension:

  - [**Google/Yandex search link fix**

    https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix)

  BEFORE:
  [image: Before adding Google/Yandex search link fix]

  AFTER:
  [image: After adding Google/Yandex search link fix]

Answer (score 10):

Using Safari, it is easy to make your own extension to handle this. I used *Develop > Show Extension Builder* and added "www.google.com" as an *Allowed Domain* and then the following script as an *End Script* in the *Injected Extension Content* section:

```
if (window.top === window) {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("l");
    for (var i in els) {
        els[i].onmousedown = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a useful approach, but the extension builder seems to have been revamped since your answer. I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 8):

I am also often annoyed by this. So my *simple* solution is to use the mobile version of Google's site:

http://www.google.com/pda
or
http://www.google.com/m     (This link does *not* work in *IE*.)

These sites will give you the URLs that go *directly* to the target sites, no more redirection.

Please note that the search results from these sites will be a little *different* from the normal ones ( by using google.com ).

Comment: doesn't work. they give the same redirects to me

Comment: The link http://www.google.com/m worked for me in IE8 but it still redirects.  http://www.google.com/pda gives direct links when opened in Firefox 6 & IE 8 (versions I tested on) but not Chrome 16

Comment: Another (probably better) one is [http://www.google.com/custom](http://www.google.com/custom).

Answer (score 7):

Just paste this in your URL bar and press enter:

```
javascript:alert(unescape(prompt("URL","").match("url=([^&]*)")[1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem.

There's an online tool that I find useful here:

[Online Tool - Convert google link to direct link for easier copying and pasting](http://industrystandardsoftware.com/online_tools/converters/convert-serp-link-to-direct-location-for-copying-and-pasting.htm)

Just bookmark that page and then paste 'horrific URLs' into the form to convert them into a normal links.

Comment: A similar Google Search Result URL Cleaner available at http://urlclean.com/ as mentioned on mozilla.general forum [Clean URLs from Google Search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.general/UHbixmekEos)

Answer (score 1):

For shorter links, selecting the green text is fine. For longer links with an ellipsis, I tend to just open the link and grab the URL from the address/awesome/omnibar.

Comment: yes, but clicking through the link and loading the entire website just so we can copy the darn URL is slow and .. unwieldy.

Comment: This does not work if the linked document is one that the browser opens in another application (e.g. PDF).

Comment: @Complicatedseebio or if the site redirects immediately (and you want to, for example, search for it in the internet archives!)