# Google copy link location annoyance?

Tags: google-search, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning off Google search results indirection](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/turning-off-google-search-results-indirection)

Sounds like a stupid question, but this really bothers me and I don't see an easy workaround. Every time I need to post link to PDF found by google, I have BIG trouble.

1. When I click on the link in the Google results and click "Copy link location", it yields the horrific URL like `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQF.....`
2. When I click the PDF (I don't want to do it, I don't want to download it!) I don't get the URL in the browser location either!
3. Copy-pasting the URL from google result is also horrific, it doesn't contain `http://` and for long URLs it is incompete.

Have you found some easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same problem. There's an online tool that I find useful [here](http://industrystandardsoftware.com/online_tools/converters/convert-serp-link-to-direct-location-for-copying-and-pasting.htm) . You can paste the 'horrific URL' and convert it into a normal link.

Comment: @JW01: I think you could post it as a separate answer (you would get some upvotes, at least from me). :)

Comment: Thanks @Sk8erPeter - I could not add an answer to this question. So, I posted the solution onto the duplicated question at:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40504/6876

Comment: @JW01: OK, I upvoted it. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google rewrite the `href` for some reason with a `rwt()` Javascript function whenever there is a `mousedown` event on the link.

[Other people](http://blog.teusink.net/2009/09/greasemonkey-script-to-change-google.html) have fixed this themselves with Greasemonkey. Maybe doesn't help if you're not a Firefox user!

Another thread discussing it [here](http://mboffin.com/post.aspx?id=1830). Their solution was to tab to the link and use the keyboard to copy the url.

Comment: Thanks for useful links. It's a pitty there is no easier solution. The second solution (open link in new tab) doesn't work in case of PDF because the link itself won't appear.

Comment: The linked Greasemonkey script doesn't work anymore, use "Google Tracking-B-Gone" by _tbolt_ instead, [here's the userscripts link](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47300).

Comment: Love the solution of avoiding the mouse right-click (+1) You usually have a key on your keyboard between right Alt and right Ctrl that shows the same context menu as right click, after you've tabbed to the link.

Comment: The Google Tracking-B-Gone that Thor linked is now also obsolete.  Another userscripts author has provided an updated version of this script [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/120330) which works for me as of 09/03/2012

Comment: _"Other people have fixed this themselves with Greasemonkey. Maybe doesn't help if you're not a Firefox user!"_ - Greasemonkey user scripts are natively supported since Google Chrome 4: http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem:

- right-clicking and copying gives me the correct URL
- the page source shows a valid link (example while searching for *Approximating the Worst-Case Execution Time of Soft Real-Time Applications*):

  ```
  <a href="http://matteocorti.ch/publications/eth_15927_slides.pdf"
    class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this,this.href,'','','','2','RMvtQpjUSw9UPW3pVTWTew','0CB8QFjAB')">
    <em>Approximating the Worst</em>-<em>Case Execution Time of Soft Real</em>-<em>time</em> <b>...</b>
  ```

Even using a non-Javascript text browser (e.g., Lyx) gives the *correct* link.

Which OS/browser are you using?

Update (on a Mac):

- Safari copies the link ignoring the onmousedown event
- Firefox copies the rewritten link

Now it seems that Safari is wrong (onmousedown should be called with right-clicks) but in this case I like the non-standard behavior :-)

Comment: Firefox 3.6. Firefox 4 and 5 sucks... anyway, now it doesn't look like browser issue - they change the link using javascript. When I open the page source, I see the same as you, but when I "copy link location" or mark it in text and select "View selection source", I see the weird-google-modified link.

Comment: It is a browser issue in the sense that if the browser ignores the Javascript event you have the correct URL. See my edited post

Comment: To reproduce - Note it only occurs when you do a search on google whilst at the same time being logged  into a google account (i.e. gmail).

Comment: @JW. - nope, I get the same result when logged out.

Comment: @Matteo, *"right-clicking and copying gives me the correct URL"* - that's really strange you can't reproduce it! Do you have javascript switched off??

Comment: @TomasT. Now (I upgraded to lion) Safari does not ignore the event anymore.

Comment: Funny you should mention that it works with no-JavaScript browsers, given that the link clearly has the correct target address *before*, but not after, you click on it (as shown when you hover it). Which, of course, does serve as a useful reminder that one approach would be to disable JavaScript entirely on Google search result pages, rather than trying to hamstring just the event handler in question.

Comment: Though, huh, now I read in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291 that the behaviour has changed for non-JS browsers.  What in the world is the point of *that*, I wonder ...