# How can I copy the URL of a PDF file from Google search results?

Tags: google-search, pdf

I ran a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=discontinuous%20games) and I want to get the URL of the second result:

[image]

But it is a link to a PDF. If I click it, I get the PDF, but not the URL (so I cannot save it in my bookmarks or send it to a friend, for example).

If I right-click and do "Copy Link", I get [a long Google-link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLzOnQwvD2AhUdhf0HHcZaD4gQFnoECCkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Felectrical-engineering-and-computer-science%2F6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010%2Flecture-notes%2FMIT6_254S10_lec06.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3XmVbgLMYVOk_T8UtGk8eL) which is very different than the original URL of the PDF.

How can I get the actual URL of the original PDF file? (I am looking for a general answer, not specifically this link).

EDIT: I have just found [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22339/20387), which solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome in English,

Option 1: Right click the URL and select Copy link Address (this works in incognito, tested in Version 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build) (arm64), I tested this in incognito after I took the below screenshot)

Option 2: Click the three dots button shown to the right of the resource title (this might not be shown to all users). This will open a modal-dialog showing the resource URL, like this

[image]

NOTE: Screenshot taken few moments ago using Chrome for Mac, Version 99.0.4844.84 (Official Build) (arm64)

Then right click the URL and select, Copy link address

[Your mileage might vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary): There are a lot of factors that might make every user experience different, like browser that they are using, browser settings like the language, if they are signed in a Google account, the particularities of that Google account like the account type, when the account was created, where it was created, if Google is running A/B tests and they are showing to you the A or B test, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I do not see these three dots! 
In any case, using Chrome, I could use Copy Link.